# C++ char to string acting funky

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
int main(){

 string word= "word";

char ciphered[word.length()];

for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
{
int current_position = (int) word[i];
int new_position = current_position + 2;
char this_char = (char) new_position;
ciphered[i] = this_char;

}



string str(ciphered);

cout << str << endl ;

}
```

When i run this it prints this:
[image]

But when i do this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(ciphered); i++)
   {
    cout << ciphered[i] << endl ;
   }
```

it prints out the same thing but without last three signs and that is correct 
but whenever i try to convert this char array to string it adds these last three weird signs and i dont know why

Comment: @Kon Same as its realation to `c`: tag spam. Though, to be fair, it's not actually c++ either. See the VLA.

Comment: You might want to run it through the appropriate compiler only. Note: you don't have to run C++ code through Java and/or C compilers, too. Modern C++ compilers directly generate binaries.

Comment: And don't post images of text!

Comment: In C++, strings are terminated with a null (char 0).  Your loop probably overwrites the string terminator, so you see some garbage chars where you're impinging on uninitialized memory.  Using `sizeof()` avoids this by setting a numeric limit to the number of chars printed.

Comment: I was to lazy i am using mingw compiler

Comment: This is c++, just: `for (const auto& i : word) str.push_back(i+2);`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this:

```
char ciphered[word.length()];
```

is not legal C++ code, though gcc may accept it. But second that you do not need really that char array, as you can access individual symbols with `std::string` itself:

```
string word= "word";
string ciphered( word.length(), ' ' );

for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
{
    ciphered[i] = word[i] + 2;
}
cout << ciphered << endl;
```

your code prints additional symbols because you did not put null terminator on C-style string and sent it through `std::ostream` which leads to UB and prints garbage that happens in memory after your char array until it suddenly finds null terminator or crash because of access of invalid memory.